# Fast-propagate exception to main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, propagation

I have a c++ multi-threaded application. Different threads are spawned at different points in the code and they run independently. Only at the stopping of the application, the destructor of each of the class is called and the thread created by each of them are stopped and joined.

Problem is, I am using exception_ptr in all the places so that the exception_ptr in that class gets set in case of exception. But I am checking for this only after join because of which until the application is closed, the exception is not displayed to the user.

I wanted a fast-propagate the exception to the main thread. The application shouldn't crash but should handle some specific error. Can someone suggest here.

Comment: Any way you do it, the main thread will need to periodically check on the running threads and handle potential exceptions then. You cannot "teleport" an exception to the main thread preemptively.

Comment: I would have a blocking queue for "messages to the user," to which any thread can push; and I would have one dedicated thread (maybe the main thread, if it isn't doing anything else until the app is finished) that waits to pop messages from the queue and display them to the user.

Comment: Assuming that the number of worker threads is known, each worker could push a "signing off" message to the queue as its last act before it terminates. The display-messages-to-the-user thread could count the number of sign-off messages that it has received, and it could shut itself down (or, if it is the main thread, join all of the workers) once the are all accounted for.